# How to read color components from ABBBBBGG GGGRRRRR two bytes format?

Tags: c#, c++, bit

I have a palette that I'm trying to decode but I always fail because I can't understand how to subtract certain bit values correctly. I always end with some crazy values.

[image]

How can I split two bytes on needed components?

PS: I added C++ tag because the answer is not language dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, get your two bytes in, say, `byte b1` and `byte b0`.

This would possibly be done as follows:

```
byte b0 = clr_bytes[0];
byte b1 = clr_bytes[1];
```

Of course this all depends on the endianness of your palette;  it may be that you need to try the opposite:

```
byte b0 = clr_bytes[1];
byte b1 = clr_bytes[0];
```

Then your components can be computed as follows:

```
byte a = b1 >> 7;
byte b = (b1 >> 2) & 0x1f;
byte g = ((b1 & 0x3) << 3) | (b0 >> 5);
byte r = b0 & 0x1f;
```

Comment: Thank you. This gives 0 - 255 values at least. But the image still have wrong colors even when I switch endianness.

Comment: This may be due to other issues.  For example, I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish with the `colors.Add(px);` stuff.  I would suggest that you try to tackle one issue at a time.  First, make sure that you can correctly decode the ABBBBBGG GGGRRRRR format into `a`, `b`, `g`, and `r`.  Then, troubleshoot what happens after that.

Comment: Got it. With that I simply add decoded color into list. later I will read bitmap that is 8bpp indexed color. 256 colors palette. Will try to understand what happens there.

Comment: It came out I need to invert each component to get correct color. Thank you.